# How can I include_bytes! into a singular external file?

Tags: rust, static-linking

I am writing a game in Rust and I am using `include_bytes!` to bundle some audio into the executable. The audio files are about ~250MB. I am compiling for both Intel Macs and ARM Macs and then creating a universal binary:

```
lipo -create -output target/universal target/intel target/arm
```

The universal binary is > 500MB and contains two copies of the audio (one for each target). Is there a way to continue to use `include_bytes!` or a similar macro and end up with one copy of the audio data in the universal executable?

Alternatively, is there a way to use `include_bytes!` but to write all of the included bytes into a singular external file (e.g. `game.dat`) that can be loaded at runtime?

I could load all the files in individually at runtime, but I like the convenience of `include_bytes!` and would prefer to continue using it (or something similar) if possible.

Comment: If you want to do the external file, you can make a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) that copies them all into some format (not with `include_bytes`, just by reading and writing files). Also if you're assigning the bytes to a const, you can try assigning them to a static instead.

Answer (score 0):

Universal binaries on Mac OS are actually a simple archive file, like a tarball, containing both binaries. That's why it's necessary for statically linked data to be duplicated.

When you run the program, only the appropriate binary for your system is loaded into memory, so you will not see double runtime memory usage. Furthermore, if your binaries contain large amounts of identical static data, this will compress extremely well, meaning you can zip up the universal binary archive and only see a small increase compared to just one of them. Typically, files are automatically compressed when transferring over a network using common protocols.

So, in practice, the only place where the doubled file size will matter is the amount of disc space it takes up on a user's machine.

If this is unacceptable, you will will need to load the data at runtime. Something like this:

```
let mut file = File::open("game.dat")?;
let mut data = Vec::new();
file.read_to_end(&mut data)?;
```